# limit 2 variable restriction

Tags: limits

I have this limit that doesn't exist:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}{(2x^2+y^2)}
$$

But there is a restriction given that changes that:
$|y|<x^2$

Considering this restriction, I have to calculate the limit again and I know it exists, but I have no idea how to calculate it...

Answer (score 2):

Write the given expression as
$${1\over 2\bigl(1+\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\bigr)}\cdot{x^2+y^2\over x^2+{1\over2}y^2}\ .$$
Here the first factor obviously converges to ${1\over4}$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. The second factor equals
$$1+{{1\over2}y^2\over x^2+{1\over2} y^2}\ .$$
Given the restriction $|y|\leq x^2$ we have the estimate
$$\left|{{1\over2}y^2\over x^2+{1\over2} y^2}\right|\leq {x^2\over2}\ ,$$
whereby the right hand side converges to $0$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Now put it all together.

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me a lot. I tried something similar, but it didn't work out. How did you get that last inequality? I actually got $\frac{x^2}{2}$ instead of just $x^2$...

Answer (score 0):

Convert the equation into polar coordinates: $x = r.cos(\theta)$ and $y = r.sin(\theta)$

$\frac{ 1 - \sqrt{ 1 - r^2} } { r^2 + r^2.cos^2(\theta) } < \frac{ 1 - \sqrt{ 1 - r^2} } { r^2 + r.|sin(\theta)| }$ ( since $|y| < x^2$ )

Now we have:

$\lim_{r \to 0 } \frac{ 1 - \sqrt{ 1 - r^2} } { r^2 + r.sin(\theta) }$ (of the form $\frac{0}{0}$)

Using L'H rule:

$\lim_{r \to 0 } \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}.(2r + |sin(\theta)|)} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, that actually is a really good idea, since it simplifies a lot the limit.